# Passing data between pages in Flutter. Empty error

Tags: flutter, dart, routes

good day to everyone.
I'm developing an app, and I need to pass a String type variable that is within a list, this String is the name of a file that I use on the next page. I tried to pass this variable but I could not. Before sending it I print it and there it is, but when I receive it on the other page it is empty, and this causes me an error. Could anyone help me?

This is the part of the code where I pass the previously declared variable:

```
_verifyPurchase(var id,bool i, String book) {
    if (user_item.contains(id) & i) {
      return "Comprado";
    }else if(!user_item.contains(id) & i){
      return "No comprado";
    }
    if (user_item.contains(id) & !i) {
      return new FlatButton(
        child: new Text("Leer"),
        onPressed: () {
          print(book);
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            new MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => new ReadBook(bookName: book,)));
        },
      );
      //return IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.library_books),color: Colors.green, onPressed: (){print(id);});
    }else if(!user_item.contains(id) & !i){
      return new FlatButton(child: new Text("Comprar"),onPressed: () {print(id);},);
      //return IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart), color: Colors.black, onPressed: (){print(id);});
    }
  }
```

In this part, I call the function:

```
content: new Text("Book"),
   actions: <Widget>[
   // usually buttons at the bottom of the dialog
       new FlatButton(
           child: new Text("Ok"),
           onPressed: () {
               Navigator.of(context).pop();
           },
        ),
        _verifyPurchase(id_book[pos], false, file_book[pos])
    ],
 )
```

This is the second-page code where I receive the variable:

```
class ReadBook extends StatefulWidget {
  ReadBook({this.bookName});
  final String bookName;
  @override
  _ReadBookState createState() => _ReadBookState();
}
```

These pages are not part of the Main, they are other pages, so I have not been able to use routes. Although it is the first time that I program in Dart and Flutter.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please, post more code and mark the line that error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value of bookName from within the State which I assume you have as you have a Stateful widget above. Add `widget.bookName` within the build method

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var book = widget.bookName;
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(child: Text(book));
    ) 
  }
```